# Is it bad to stop the Mountain Lion installer halfway through an install?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I already have Mountain Lion.  I started installing it again (it warns you that you already have it).  I realized I don't need to install it again.  The install is halfway finished.  Can I just quit the install, or is it actively overwriting files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm it appears from a screenshot I received Mountain Lion was only downloading and not actually installing:

[image]

The solution is to:

1. Check for unfinished downloads
2. It will reload everything telling you it's all installed already
3. The download will reset

Done!